# Multidimensional taylor series $sin (x^3y^2) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

A homework of mine was to compute the Taylor series of $f(x,y)=\sin(x^3y^2)$ around $(0,0)$ to the 25th order. I assumed, as $\sin(z)=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$, that I could just plug in my $x^3y^2$ in the formula and that this was covered by the identity theorem for power series. Is this right? Can somebody give me the exact reasoning?

Comment: @Matthew I see no problem in your valutations: the series representation of a function admits composition. You can also demonstrate that the series coincide with the function for every constant $x$ and for every constant $y$ so the analytic continuation of the function will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. $\sin(z)$ is not only an analytic function, but an entire function:
$$ \sin(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \tag{1}$$
holds as an identity for *any* value of $z\in\mathbb{C}$. It follows that:
$$ \sin(x^3 y^2) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{6n+3}y^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{2}$$
holds as an identity for every value of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. But the RHS of $(2)$ is a multivariate Taylor series centered at $(0,0)$, and the multivariate Taylor series is unique.